# Getting data from two tables with SUM quantity of within certain period of Time

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables below:

**Orderdetails**

```
OrderNumber
quantityordered
priceEach
```

**Orders**

```
OrderNumber
orderDate
```

***Question:***
orderDate look like this: `2005-01-01. 2005-02-01. 2003-04-30.....etc`.
The total sum of sales = quantityordered * priceEach

I have to find out the todal SUM of sales in Feb 2005 ONLY
So far I have:

```
SELECT orderdate FROM orders WHERE orderdate LIKE'2005-02%';
```

AND

```
SELECT sum(quantityordered * priceEach) as Total FROM orderdetails;
```

However, how can I combined these 2 into 1 to answer the question?
Greatly appreciate for your great help in advanced!

AlexK

Comment: Look up how to use `JOIN`. Also don't match dates with text pattens use range based tests.

Comment: Still struggling? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use date functions like [Year()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) and [Month()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) to get year and month number out of a MySQL date, respectively.
- Simply do an [Inner Join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) on both the tables, using `OrderNumber`.
- Calculate [Sum()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) on sales, where the year and month matches your conditions.
- Also, it is a good habit to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) when dealing with multiple tables in a Join, Subquery, Derived tables based approach, etc.

Try the following:

```
SELECT SUM(od.quantityordered * od.priceEach) 
FROM Orders AS o 
INNER JOIN Orderdetails AS od ON o.OrderNumber = od.OrderNumber 
WHERE YEAR(o.orderDate) = 2005 
  AND MONTH(o.orderDate) = 2
```