# Complicated data getting from different tables

Tags: mysql

I need to find the employee who produced the highest sales amount in the first quarter of 2004...

I have tried quite a few ways but its too complicated. Anyone mind to give me a hand please?

So far I have:

```
(quantityOrdered * PriceEach) as PerOrdertotalprice

where payments.paymentDate(Date) between '2014-01-01' and '2014-04-30'
```

Thanks!

Comment: MySQL 5.5+ has a year and quarter functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter. .. Would make more sense to use i geuss if the question is `first quarter of 2004` something like `... WHERE YEAR(date) = 2014 AND QUARTER(date) = 1`

Comment: why you delete the diagrame picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do **Joins** between various tables, based on their relationships (as expressed in the diagram).
- Compute total sales value using [`Sum()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function, for an `employeeNumber` group.
- Order by total sales value in Descending order, and use `LIMIT 1` to consider the employee with highest total sales value
- Use date functions like [`Year()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) and [`Quarter()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter) in your `where` condition, to check for `year = 2004` and `quarter = 1`

Try the following:

```
SELECT e.employeeNumber, 
       e.firstName, 
       e.lastName, 
       SUM(od.quantityordered * od.priceEach) AS total_sales 
FROM orders AS o 
JOIN orderdetails AS od ON o.OrderNumber = od.OrderNumber 
JOIN customers AS c ON c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber 
JOIN employees AS e ON e.employeeNumber = c.salesRepEmployeeNumber 
WHERE YEAR(o.orderDate) = 2004 
  AND QUARTER(o.orderDate) = 1 
GROUP BY e.employeeNumber, e.firstName, e.lastName 
ORDER BY total_sales DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `MONTH(o.orderDate) = 2 ` is not the same as a quarter.. You should be using `MONTH(o.orderDate) BETWEEN 1 and 4` or `QUARTER(o.orderDate) = 1`

Comment: @RaymondNijland yeah i was in the process of updating. was actually expanding my answer given to same OP in a previous question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52575979/2469308

Comment: @RaymondNijland no there is only one-to-many relationship between employee to customer. so a particular customer will always have only one employee assigned to it.

Comment: yes never mind i readed the table diagram pretty wrong right there. I geuss i need some more coffee right now..

Comment: @RaymondNijland checking this image: [Entity Relationship Diagram Symbols](https://images.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fd2slcw3kip6qmk.cloudfront.net%2Fmarketing%2Fpages%2Fchart%2Ferd-symbols%2FERD-Notation.PNG&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lucidchart.com%2Fpages%2FER-diagram-symbols-and-meaning&docid=zjiKgNrOPvShgM&tbnid=I6Qu9e5T6JYKlM%3A&vet=1&w=416&h=315&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim)

It is **Zero Or One** (on employee side) to **Zero or many**. So basically an employee can have multiple customers. But a customer will always have either one employee or none assigned to him

Comment: indeed i've upvoted, this query makes complete sense on this table diagram...And should give the correct results.